# jQuery slideDown menu doesn't work until 2nd hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

## What I have:

I have a basic drop-down list that I'm using jQuery to slideUp and slideDown on hover.

## What I need:

I need the drop-down to slideDown on the first hover and every hover thereafter. Currently, the first hover is always ignored. The slideDown doesn't take affect until the second hover.

## Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/tbc3rkk3/2/

*Please note:*

1. *The problem doesn't occur in this example but the code should no less provide requisite context.*
2. *I can't link to a live version of the website I'm developing.*

## What I've tried:

There already exists [a very similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3418728/2971649).

The selected answer suggests that via CSS, I set the `ul` to `display:none;` however this is something that's already applied in my case.

## My question:

Why is the first hover/slideDown being obstructed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove this part to make the animation works properly:

```
#language:hover .language_dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbc3rkk3/7/)

**Note**: You can also add `stop()` function to prevent multiple hover useless animations.

```
$("#language").hover(function () {
    $(".language_dropdown").stop().slideDown("slow");
}, function() {
    $(".language_dropdown").stop().slideUp("slow");
});
```

Comment: Your solution (removing problematic CSS) works and the `stop()` function provides a solution a problem I didn't outline but is equally appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `slideToggle`?

```
$("#language").on('click', function () {
    $(".language_dropdown").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

[See my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s8th2gbd/).

Note: executing the function on hover is not recommended, as it would trigger much more often and users on mobile phones and tablets are not properly addressed. A click is a better approach. See my updated JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks but your JSFiddle output doesn't slideDown. Secondly, if hover not recommended, what _is_ recommended?

Comment: @TirthPatel Great feedback. Clarus, I updated my Fiddle, a click is a better solution.